# Error creating consenter: failed to restore persisted raft data: failed to create or read WAL: failed to open WAL: fileutil: file already locked

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Orderers are failing when to try to create a channel

Setup:

- Three Orderers | Tried with 5 orderers also
- kubernetes
- Raft Consensus
- 1.4.3 & 1.4.1
- Its working perfectly with docker swarm

below the error log from one of the orderer

```
2019-09-04 13:02:11.488 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] HandleChain -> INFO 079 EvictionSuspicion not set, defaulting to 10m0s
    2019-09-04 13:02:11.489 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] createOrReadWAL -> INFO 07a Found WAL data at path '/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal/nath41channel', replaying it channel=nath41channel node=2
    2019-09-04 13:02:11.489 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newChainSupport -> PANI 07b [channel: nath41channel] Error creating consenter: failed to restore persisted raft data: failed to create or read WAL: failed to open WAL: fileutil: file already locked
    panic: [channel: nath41channel] Error creating consenter: failed to restore persisted raft data: failed to create or read WAL: failed to open WAL: fileutil: file already locked

    goroutine 86 [running]:
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc00018bce0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x515
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc000134280, 0x4, 0x1040dcc, 0x2a, 0xc000721548, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc000134280, 0x1040dcc, 0x2a, 0xc000721548, 0x2, 0x2)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc000134288, 0x1040dcc, 0x2a, 0xc000721548, 0x2, 0x2)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.newChainSupport(0xc000170000, 0xc00028f5e0, 0xc0004ef260, 0x1145580, 0x1b8f970, 0xc0004ed3a0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/chainsupport.go:74 +0x710
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.(*Registrar).newChain(0xc000170000, 0xc0008dc870)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:327 +0x1df
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.(*BlockWriter).WriteConfigBlock(0xc0005a8000, 0xc000483940, 0xc0008e3360, 0xb, 0xb)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/blockwriter.go:118 +0x2f3
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft.(*Chain).writeConfigBlock(0xc0001f8f00, 0xc000483940, 0x7)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft/chain.go:1266 +0x1b4
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft.(*Chain).writeBlock(0xc0001f8f00, 0xc000483940, 0x7)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft/chain.go:839 +0x18f
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft.(*Chain).apply(0xc0001f8f00, 0xc0004ea240, 0x3, 0x4)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft/chain.go:1030 +0x250
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft.(*Chain).serveRequest(0xc0001f8f00)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft/chain.go:748 +0x954
    created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft.(*Chain).Start
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft/chain.go:336 +0x1e0

2019-09-04 19:12:24.951 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] commitBlock -> PANI 03c [channel: rak25syschannel] Could not append block: unexpected Previous block hash. Expected PreviousHash = [99f567ec6a4f92583076be9d414c47f990559a0f5f24bd0273ba13bbfefd60f8], PreviousHash referred in the latest block= [d1507d8cf004d1dd7cd7940eb3c0c314fd82dcafd1e6edf784df3893cc938a64]
panic: [channel: rak25syschannel] Could not append block: unexpected Previous block hash. Expected PreviousHash = [99f567ec6a4f92583076be9d414c47f990559a0f5f24bd0273ba13bbfefd60f8], PreviousHash referred in the latest block= [d1507d8cf004d1dd7cd7940eb3c0c314fd82dcafd1e6edf784df3893cc938a64]
```

Complete log of one of the orderer: http://ideone.com/TidhFt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution !!

Its because I am doing automation, three orderers generate three genesis blocks using supportive tools.

Even though it is the same configuration we shouldn't do because when multiple genesis blocks it starts forking thats the way hyperledger fabric protocol designed

Comment: How did you solve it exactly ? I am facing the exact same issue, I'm using docker-compose to boot 3 orderers with RAFT consensus and from time to time when trying to create a channel this error occurs. When running tests locally I rarely have the error but it makes the CI fails almost every time

Comment: Hey Thomas please do not generate genesis block for each Orderer, use single one for all orderers

Comment: That is already what I do, generate a single genesis block and mount it in a volume for each orderer but I'm still getting this error :/ I am doing some tests and it seems that sleeping for 1 minute after booting the whole network avoids the problem but I still don't understand why. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ThomasMilox , this bug will be fixed  when https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/pull/2934 will be merged